# Associate formdata with filedata in MultipartFormDataStreamProvider for a multiple file upload

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am creating a RESTful web service that will allow end users to upload files with relevant metadata (for each uploaded file). I am looking into using the [MultipartFormDataStreamProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatastreamprovider%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) class. The class allows reading the formdata (metadata in my case) from it's formdata property and the files from it's filedata property. I am referring to the sample [Sending HTML Form Data](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2) on the ASP.net site for this purpose.

**Query:**

How do I associate the metadata POSTed in the formdata to the uploaded files in filedata?

**e.g.** Assume that the metadata in formdata is *[{"property1": value1, "property2": value2}, {"property1": value3, "property2":value4}]* and 2 files were uploaded with the POST request. How do I know which item in the JSON data (available in the formdata property) corresponds to which uploaded file/s (available in filedata property)? Will this be in the same order as it was POSTed from the client?

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to stumble upon this today... (for those who may have the same confusion)

Seems like MultipartFormDataStreamProvider is "to process MIME Multipart HTML Form data which is a combination of form data and file content."
And hence you have a list of form values along with a number of files.. **all are part of the same post request.**

but like in many exapmles on the web one way to get to the  is

```
// This illustrates how to get the file names.
foreach (MultipartFileData file in streamProvider.FileData)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
    Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);


// Show all the key-value pairs.
foreach (var key in streamProvider.FormData.AllKeys)
{
    foreach (var val in streamProvider.FormData.GetValues(key))
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));
        }
}
```